# Spring Boot Integration test error of CIRCULAR REFERENCE :io.zonky.test.db.provider.ProviderException

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, integration-testing

I am working on Spring Boot Application that contains unit and integration test cases to check functionalities.

Docker is running with Podman and it working fine.

I am using POSTGRES database server that configured on my machine. But while running Integration test, the test are getting ignored with the error : CIRCULAR REFERENCE:io.zonky.test.db.provider.ProviderException: Unexpected error when preparing a database cluster; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration

**Detailed Stack Trace :**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
    at io.zonky.test.db.EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.forEachDatabase(EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.java:90)
    at io.zonky.test.db.EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.resetDatabases(EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.java:58)
    at io.zonky.test.db.EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.beforeTestClass(EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.java:34)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestClass(TestContextManager.java:213)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.beforeAll(SpringExtension.java:77)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllCallbacks$7(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:189)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:132)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
    Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
        at io.zonky.test.db.EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.forEachDatabase(EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.java:90)
        at io.zonky.test.db.EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.resetDatabases(EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.java:58)
        at io.zonky.test.db.EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.afterTestClass(EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.java:54)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestClass(TestContextManager.java:488)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.afterAll(SpringExtension.java:86)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllCallbacks$13(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:421)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllCallbacks$14(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:421)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeAfterAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:421)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:213)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:77)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:145)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:145)
        ... 27 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is io.zonky.test.db.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: io.zonky.test.db.provider.ProviderException: Unexpected error when preparing a database cluster; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:125)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
        ... 43 more
    Caused by: io.zonky.test.db.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: io.zonky.test.db.provider.ProviderException: Unexpected error when preparing a database cluster; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration
        at io.zonky.test.db.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.wrapAndThrowUnchecked(Futures.java:1571)
        at io.zonky.test.db.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.getUnchecked(Futures.java:1556)
        at io.zonky.test.db.context.DefaultDatabaseContext.awaitDatabase(DefaultDatabaseContext.java:282)
        at io.zonky.test.db.context.DefaultDatabaseContext.getDatabase(DefaultDatabaseContext.java:126)
        at io.zonky.test.db.context.DatabaseTargetSource.getTarget(DatabaseTargetSource.java:32)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:192)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy206.toString(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951)
        at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:168)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper.logPersistenceUnitInformation(LogHelper.java:53)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:191)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:168)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:52)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
        ... 59 more
    Caused by: io.zonky.test.db.provider.ProviderException: Unexpected error when preparing a database cluster; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration
        at io.zonky.test.db.provider.postgres.DockerPostgresDatabaseProvider.createDatabase(DockerPostgresDatabaseProvider.java:117)
        at io.zonky.test.db.provider.postgres.DockerPostgresDatabaseProvider.createTemplate(DockerPostgresDatabaseProvider.java:102)
        at io.zonky.test.db.provider.common.TemplatingDatabaseProvider.createTemplate(TemplatingDatabaseProvider.java:129)
        at io.zonky.test.db.provider.common.TemplatingDatabaseProvider.lambda$createTemplateIfPossible$1(TemplatingDatabaseProvider.java:171)
        at io.zonky.test.db.provider.common.TemplatingDatabaseProvider$TemplateWrapper.loadTemplate(TemplatingDatabaseProvider.java:294)
        at io.zonky.test.db.provider.common.TemplatingDatabaseProvider$TemplateWrapper.access$200(TemplatingDatabaseProvider.java:224)
        at io.zonky.test.db.provider.common.TemplatingDatabaseProvider.createTemplateIfPossible(TemplatingDatabaseProvider.java:171)
        at io.zonky.test.db.provider.common.TemplatingDatabaseProvider.createDatabase(TemplatingDatabaseProvider.java:112)
        at io.zonky.test.db.provider.common.TemplatingDatabaseProvider.createDatabase(TemplatingDatabaseProvider.java:104)
        at io.zonky.test.db.provider.common.PrefetchingDatabaseProvider$PrefetchingTask.lambda$forPreparer$0(PrefetchingDatabaseProvider.java:391)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at io.zonky.test.db.provider.common.PrefetchingDatabaseProvider$PrefetchingTask.run(PrefetchingDatabaseProvider.java:420)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration
        at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.lambda$getFirstValidStrategy$7(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:215)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:408)
        at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.getFirstValidStrategy(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:207)
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.getOrInitializeStrategy(DockerClientFactory.java:136)
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:178)
        at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.getDockerClient(LazyDockerClient.java:14)
        at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.authConfig(LazyDockerClient.java:12)
        at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:310)
        at io.zonky.test.db.provider.postgres.DockerPostgresDatabaseProvider$DatabaseInstance.<init>(DockerPostgresDatabaseProvider.java:173)
        at io.zonky.test.db.provider.postgres.DockerPostgresDatabaseProvider$DatabaseInstance.<init>(DockerPostgresDatabaseProvider.java:137)
        at io.zonky.test.db.provider.postgres.DockerPostgresDatabaseProvider$1.load(DockerPostgresDatabaseProvider.java:77)
        at io.zonky.test.db.provider.postgres.DockerPostgresDatabaseProvider$1.load(DockerPostgresDatabaseProvider.java:75)
        at io.zonky.test.db.shaded.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3708)
        at io.zonky.test.db.shaded.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2416)
        at io.zonky.test.db.shaded.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2299)
        at io.zonky.test.db.shaded.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2212)
        at io.zonky.test.db.shaded.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4147)
        at io.zonky.test.db.shaded.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4151)
        at io.zonky.test.db.shaded.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:5140)
        at io.zonky.test.db.provider.postgres.DockerPostgresDatabaseProvider.createDatabase(DockerPostgresDatabaseProvider.java:113)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is io.zonky.test.db.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: io.zonky.test.db.provider.ProviderException: Unexpected error when preparing a database cluster; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: io.zonky.test.db.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: io.zonky.test.db.provider.ProviderException: Unexpected error when preparing a database cluster; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration
    at io.zonky.test.db.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.wrapAndThrowUnchecked(Futures.java:1571)
    at io.zonky.test.db.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.getUnchecked(Futures.java:1556)
    at io.zonky.test.db.context.DefaultDatabaseContext.awaitDatabase(DefaultDatabaseContext.java:282)
    at io.zonky.test.db.context.DefaultDatabaseContext.getDatabase(DefaultDatabaseContext.java:126)
    at io.zonky.test.db.context.DatabaseTargetSource.getTarget(DatabaseTargetSource.java:32)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:192)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy187.toString(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper.logPersistenceUnitInformation(LogHelper.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:168)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:52)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
    ... 57 more
    [CIRCULAR REFERENCE:io.zonky.test.db.provider.ProviderException: Unexpected error when preparing a database cluster; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration]
```

I have tried many solution like updated to latest version on zonky :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.zonky.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>embedded-database-spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>io.zonky.test</groupId>
     <artifactId>embedded-postgres</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.6</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

But it didn't worked.

Tried `@AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase(type = AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase.DatabaseType.POSTGRES, provider = ZONKY)`

Then also it throwing same error : CIRCULAR REFERENCE:io.zonky.test.db.provider.ProviderException: Unexpected error when preparing a database cluster

**Detailed Stack trace**

```
Caused by: io.zonky.test.db.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: io.zonky.test.db.provider.ProviderException: Unexpected error when preparing a database cluster; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process [C:\Users\NEELAM~1.SHA\AppData\Local\Temp\embedded-pg\PG-aaa7d03a0c0eb51f9510c27dc059d022\bin\initdb.exe, -A, trust, -U, postgres, -D, C:\Users\NEELAM~1.SHA\AppData\Local\Temp\epg14265419788948759198, -E, UTF-8] failed
    at io.zonky.test.db.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.wrapAndThrowUnchecked(Futures.java:1571)
    at io.zonky.test.db.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.getUnchecked(Futures.java:1556)
    at io.zonky.test.db.context.DefaultDatabaseContext.awaitDatabase(DefaultDatabaseContext.java:282)
    at io.zonky.test.db.context.DefaultDatabaseContext.getDatabase(DefaultDatabaseContext.java:126)
    at io.zonky.test.db.context.DatabaseTargetSource.getTarget(DatabaseTargetSource.java:32)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:192)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy187.toString(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper.logPersistenceUnitInformation(LogHelper.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:168)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:52)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
    ... 57 more
    [CIRCULAR REFERENCE:io.zonky.test.db.provider.ProviderException: Unexpected error when preparing a database cluster; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process [C:\Users\NEELAM~1.SHA\AppData\Local\Temp\embedded-pg\PG-aaa7d03a0c0eb51f9510c27dc059d022\bin\initdb.exe, -A, trust, -U, postgres, -D, C:\Users\NEELAM~1.SHA\AppData\Local\Temp\epg14265419788948759198, -E, UTF-8] failed]
```

What can be more possible way to resolve the issue of tests?

Comment: I am facing the same issue.

Comment: i have also the same problem

Comment: I had the same problem and adding 

`@AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase(type = AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase.DatabaseType.POSTGRES, provider = ZONKY)`


along with 


```<dependency>
     <groupId>io.zonky.test</groupId>
     <artifactId>embedded-postgres</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.0</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>```

fixed the problem

Comment: I am facing the same issue, even though I have the latest dependencies!

Answer (score 3):

upgrading embedded-postgres to 2.0.0 should fix the issue

```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>io.zonky.test</groupId>
     <artifactId>embedded-postgres</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.0</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
```

Comment: testImplementation 'io.zonky.test:embedded-postgres:2.0.2'
for gradle

Comment: still didn't fix my issue

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the same problem. My test works when running locally, but it doesn't work with Docker.

In the end, I did the following steps and fixed my test:

1. added these lines to the Dockerfile  after the first line which sets a base image (see [the official documentation](https://github.com/zonkyio/embedded-database-spring-test?tab=readme-ov-file#running-tests-in-docker-does-not-work)):

```
RUN groupadd --system --gid 1000 test
RUN useradd --system --gid test --uid 1000 --shell /bin/bash --create-home test
USER test
```

After that, my Dockerfile became like this.

```
FROM maven:3-openjdk-17 as build

RUN groupadd --system --gid 1000 test
RUN useradd --system --gid test --uid 1000 --shell /bin/bash --create-home test
USER test

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
COPY pom.xml .
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.m2 mvn dependency:go-offline -B

COPY src src
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.m2 mvn package spring-boot:repackage -T4

FROM openjdk:17
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/target/*.jar /usr/app/app.jar
```

2. changed `@AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase()` to `@AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase(type = POSTGRES, provider = ZONKY)`
3. added the new dependency to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.zonky.test</groupId>
      <artifactId>embedded-postgres</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.6</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```